# echo -e "\e[8m" does not work on console terminal

Tags: linux

I am trying to use echo -e "\e[8m" (invisible) to hide the startup init scripts from printing on the console while booting on my Centos 6 (32-bit) server but it does not hide the text. Even if i just use it on the terminal like - echo -e "\e[8mHello" it prints Hello. 
I have installed ncurser packages and tried setting TERM environment variable to different terminal emulators which support "\e[8m (invisible)" capability but still it does not work as expected.
However if i ssh to this machine from virtual box or any gui based IDEs, then it works on the corresponding xterm terminals.

What do i need to do to make this "\e[8m" capability work on my system.

Comment: Why are you hiding command output with ANSI escape sequences? That's totally unreliable -- the command can always output the reset sequence. You should redirect that output to `/dev/null` -- for example: `mycommand >/dev/null`.

Comment: Two reasons i did not use redirecting it to /dev/null 

1. It will cause /var/log/bootlog to be empty 
2. After the bootup i need these init services (network/syslog) to print the messages normally.

Comment: If you need that output, redirect it to a file.

Comment: could be done but needs to do it for every service.

Comment: >/dev/null not very feasible solution in my case.